# I want to post a string msg on facebook's wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall

I have my appId for facebook. Which type of configuration and auth should I require.

Now I want to post a String message on Facebook wall when some condition true. What should I do?

Comment: there are lot of facebook tutorials over the internet, i think you should start searching.

Comment: then send me a good example that solve my problem easily.

Comment: thanks for these answers.. let me check and integrete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through below link . It might helps you a lot.

[Facebook android sdk](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/tag/android-facebook-tutorial/)

you can also send message directly using the below code.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", message);
mFacebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
```

you can create facebook object and using request method you can directly post to user wall. Before posting on wall you must have to login into facebook .

Comment: amm i have appId,and app user so  i want to send msg direcvtly.

Answer (score 1):

I am just giving you the first link i found on the search , take a look it, it has all the things you require...

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/

Comment: amm i have appId,and app user so  i want to send msg direcvtly.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Facebook SDK for android

> https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

also Facebook Android Tutorial It will help you.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Comment: amm i have appId,and app user so  i want to send msg direcvtly.